# Hide wordpress prefix in url using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm managing a wordpress blog like `example.com/site/hello-world/` and I want to hide the site prefix. One thing I can do is to reinstall but that's not suitable as the blog is huge.

so how can I do with with .htacess?

Comment: `Alias / /site/` should do this

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on assuming you havent already
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Here are the tags used

```
L  - Last
NC - Ignore (No) Case comparison
R  - External redirection with 302
```

Comment: what is `$1 [L,NC,R]` here?

Comment: @Jennifer added in post

Comment: This will redirect to example.com which it has no wordpress installed. My wp app is at example.com/site