# Creating alias using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Says I've my WordPress blog installed in a folder call site and the URL has become `example.com/site/sample-post`. How do I change it to something like `example.com/sample-post` using URL rewrite?

Doing this `RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]` is redirect, what I want is alias.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide wordpress prefix in url using .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499435/hide-wordpress-prefix-in-url-using-htaccess)

Comment: please don't post same question repeatedly.

Comment: @hjpotter92 please I couldn't find any solution yet.

Comment: @Jennifer continue with your old question, no need to create a new one.